# MySQL and User level logging

Tags: mysql, logging, database, users

I have been looking at logging only certain users activity in MySQL. I found that the logging could be enabled or disabled for all users but one of the service using the db does a *lot* of queries and therefore I would like to only log specific users.

Google told me that a flag can be SET to enable disable logging, however, I cannot modify the service DB connection code and asking every single user to enable logging before they do anything might not be as reliable as I want.

So, do you know if there is any way to log only a set of users queries ?

Thanks !

Comment: MySQL does not have this functionality natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install mySQL proxy and do your logging there.

Answer (score 0):

newer versions of mysql support logging to tables. this could be abused in interesting ways:

- write a trigger to delete rows from the logging table that do not correspond to the users you are interested in monitoring.
- partition the logging table on username. periodically empty the partitions for the users you are not interested in monitoring.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, the main reason not to log the service is to prevent massive performance drop, if I do it the way you suggest I will still have the performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

You could enable logging globally, then alter the connection code to disable logging for the high load users that you don't want to monitor. I can think of a couple of cases in my environment where this would be most efficient, so it might work for you, too.